# How can I attach a user to another user with user meta

Tags: users, user-meta, user-registration

I've been searching for an answer for a number of days with no luck. I was hoping one of you might have dabbled with this before, and could point me in the right direction.

I am trying to find the correct combination of WordPress functions that would allow me to have a one-to-many parent/child relationship between users, so I can use this relationship to both show the parent user various data sets form the child user, as well as to track certain actions the child user takes, so I can apply functionality that is trigger by those actions ... and other possibilities like this.

I'd want it to be somewhat automated ... so, something like giving the parent user the ability to create a unique invite registration form, that when a new user registers, it associates that user to the person who gave them the invitation.

I can give you guys specifics of the project I need this for, so you have context. I figured I would start here, and perhaps spark up a conversation.

The first step is to be able to connect the users together using user meta. I'd try to do this manually first, so I know it is working the way I anticipate.

I hope this post is appropriate. I tried to find something that could clue me in, but I had no luck.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use custom user meta fields or different database table for the user relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to build it yourself or are you looking for plugins to provide that function?

A quick search brought up [InviteReferrals](https://wordpress.org/plugins/invitereferrals-customer-referral-program/) that looks like it does what you want (well, the hard part at least, the output on your site is probably something you want to have influence over). 
I'm sure there are others, this was just the first that popped up. Please note that I can't say anything about its quality, and it has few (but quite mixed) ratings.

Building that yourself shouldn't be too hard either, I'm sure that'd be a nice project to dive deeper into WordPress development. [Customizing the Registration Form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form) looks like a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was helpful. To answer your question, I am definitely interested in increasing my knowledge of WordPress, and the available functionality I can tap into.

You are correct, it looks like the Customizing the Registration Form is an appropriate starting point. As far as being able to connect the new registrant user to the original user that sent the invite is where I see myself getting stuck.

@Abdul Awal 16 mentioned using User Meta fields to connect the two users together. Is this what you would do, as well?

Thanks again!